# How to access/permission specific folder in react native using react-native-scoped-storage

Tags: android, react-native, storage, android-permissions, scoped-storage

I successfully implemented react-native-scoped-storage package
. when i run the following code it opens the file explorer at root directory but i want to access "storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/Whatsapp/Media/.Statuses/" directly. how can i do that ?

my code :

```
 let dir = await (await ScopedStorage.openDocumentTree(true));

  if (dir) {
    console.log({data, path, uri});
  }
```

please give answer, i am searching this issue from 5 day